# How to convert an integer to a string with a fixed number of digits in c++?

Tags: c++, string

For examples, with 4 digits, convert 0 to "0000"; and 12 to "0012".

Any good way in c++?

Sorry not making it clear, my compiler doesn't support snprintf, and I want a function like

std::string ToString(int value, int digitsCount);

Comment: `<sstream>` provides that sort of formatting capability, as does ye olde `sprintf`.

Comment: @chris you mean `snprintf()`, right?

Comment: @H2CO3, Indeed. I don't use it, so I guess I could lie and argue I was talking about the base of that set of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string ToString(int value,int digitsCount)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os<<setfill('0')<<setw(digitsCount)<<value;
    return os.str();
}

int main()
{
    cout<<ToString(0,4)<<endl;
    cout<<ToString(12,4)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
char buf[5];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%04d", intVal);
```

Comment: No, please, don't `sprintf()`! If you use this function family, use the secure version!

Comment: @Caribou That's not a problem, the `printf()` family of functions works just fine in C++, but really, the secure variations should be used.

Comment: @H2CO3, I'm using sprintf on a static char buffer allocated on the stack with a length specified by me. so given all of this, sprintf() is secure enough. I posted the snprintf() version if that's more preferable :)

Comment: @H2CO3 I suppose it is probably a reasonable lightweight way of outputting what the OP wants - streams just come to me more readily these days....

Comment: @Caribou the problem with sprintf is that one day you WILL eventually change your buffer from static to mallocated one, you also will change its size, etc. So it IS insecure. Because we're humans and we make mistakes. Why not prevent them? Adding an 'n' should not hurt.

Comment: agreed, H2CO3. Especially, since providing a snippet of code makes one have 0 control over where that thing is going to end up :)

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not defending sprintf at all - why is that comment directed at me? and using streams avoid the size of the buffer altogether....